# Django django.core.files.File(file-like object) returns File('None')

Tags: django, file, bytesio

I have a io.BytesIO object that I want to convert to a valid Django File object. My code is simple:

```
ret_file = File(file_object)

(Pdb) ret_file
<File: None>
(Pdb) file_object
<_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ab3fa1d51d0>
```

I evaluate it as follows and it goes for the else path, like it is not a valid File object:

```
if file_object:
    #do_stuff()
else:
    #log_error()
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try to use it? Because in-memory objects have no name, so the representation returns `<File: None>`. If you wouldn't have a file, it wouldn't display anything.

Comment: You are right. I edited the question and posted a solution to the actual problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it IS a valid File object. The only thing is that the name is None.

So assigning a name to the File object, it stops being evaluated as False

```
(Pdb) 'yes' if file_object else 'no'
'no'

file_object.name = 'my name'

(Pdb) 'yes' if file_object else 'no'
'yes'
```

And that's it

Comment: I would actually call that a bug in Django. They specifically override `__bool__`, to evaluate the presence of a name. It's rather unexpected and don't know why they do it.

Comment: I agree. I'll file a bug. Meanwhile the solution is a workaround (currently for Django 3.1.3)